# Using Switch in DropDownMenu (Switch toggled state not saving when menu closed) - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, material-ui, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to build a to-do app for Android using Material 3 & Jetpack Compose. I'm trying to create a drop down menu that allows users to filter which "Category" of tasks they see on the screen. I'm using Switch to do this.
[Drop down menu w/ Switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyJAx.png)

When I click to toggle a category off, it does get removed from the screen. However, when I close the drop down menu the category reappears. I'm very much a beginner, and I'm having a hard time understanding how to save the Switch state when the menu is closed. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is my current code:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun TaskPageLayout(
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues()
) {
    val categories = listOf(
        Category("Home"),
        Category("Work"),
        Category("Chores")
    )

    val tasks = listOf(
        Task("Task 1", categories[0], "High", "Easy"),
        Task("Task 2", categories[1], "Medium", "Medium"),
        Task("Task 3", categories[2], "Low", "Hard"),
        Task("Task 4", categories[0], "High", "Easy")
    )

    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val categoryCheckedState = remember { mutableStateMapOf<Category, Boolean>() }
    categories.forEach { category ->
        categoryCheckedState[category] = true
    }

    var selectedCategories by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList<Category>()) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(contentPadding)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
        ) {
            Box {
                ElevatedButton(onClick = { expanded = true }) {
                    Text("Category")
                }
                DropdownMenu(
                    expanded = expanded,
                    onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
                ) {
                    categories.forEach { category ->
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            text = { Text(category.name) },
                            trailingIcon = {
                                Switch(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .semantics {
                                            contentDescription =
                                                "Switch to choose which categories to view"
                                        },
                                    checked = categoryCheckedState[category] ?: false,
                                    onCheckedChange = { isChecked ->
                                        categoryCheckedState[category] = isChecked
                                    }
                                )
                            },
                            onClick = {
                                categoryCheckedState[category] = !categoryCheckedState[category]!!
                                selectedCategories = if (category in selectedCategories) {
                                    selectedCategories - category
                                } else {
                                    selectedCategories + category
                                }
                            },
                            modifier = Modifier.clickable(
                                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                                indication = null
                            ) {}
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            ElevatedButton(
                onClick = { /* Handle button click */ }
            ) {
                Text("Priority")
            }
            ElevatedButton(onClick = { /* Handle button click */ }) {
                Text("Difficulty")
            }
        }

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 16.dp)
        ) {
            val groupedTasks = tasks.groupBy { it.category }

            categories.forEach { category ->
                if (categoryCheckedState[category] == true) {
                    stickyHeader {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .background(Color.LightGray)
                                .padding(8.dp)
                        ) {
                            Text(
                                text = category.name,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    items(groupedTasks[category] ?: emptyList()) { task ->
                        Text(text = task.name, modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any feedback <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
categories.forEach { category ->
        categoryCheckedState[category] = true
    }
```

Every time `TaskPageLayout` is recomposed this code runs and sets all your map values to `true`.
I assume that you want to initiate the map with all of the values set to true, but not set them to true every time a recomposition occurs.

Remove that segment and initiate `categoryCheckedState` like this:

```
val categoryCheckedState = remember {
        mutableStateMapOf<Category, Boolean>().apply {
            categories.forEach { category ->
                this[category] = true
            }
        }
    }
```

And you should be good to go :D

Comment: That worked wonderfully!! Thank you so much I was feeling so discouraged, but this fix gives me hope lol <3<3<3

Comment: Glad to hear it! The code looks good to me, better than "beginner" for sure. One thing-- would you mind approving this answer? Thanks and best of luck!